# split a string having multiple conditions using regex

Tags: java, regex

I m having a string as below

```
  This is a test\nAnother test\n#art\n#paintings#collections
```

From which i have pick the words - art, paintings,collections.

I have written a java program for that [here](http://ideone.com/9v7o9U). The code -

```
  String str = "This is a test\nAnother test\n#art\n#paintings#collections";


    String tag_name ="";
    String[] sp = str.split(" |\n");
    for (int j =0; j<sp.length; j++) {
        //System.out.println(""+sp[j]);
        if ( String.valueOf(sp[j].charAt(0)).equals("#")) {                
            tag_name = sp[j];
            String[] np = tag_name.split("#");
            for (int k = 0; k<np.length; k++) {
                if(np[k].length() >0 ) {
                    tag_name = np[k].replaceAll("\n", "");
                    System.out.println(""+ np[k]);
                }
            }                
            //System.out.println("" + tag_name);
        }
    }
```

Please suggest how can i do this using a more strong regex code.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: it is having split two times and two for loops. i thought if it can be reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirements, you want to find all words following `#`. If so, this works:

```
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
/**
   <P>{@code java ArtTypesXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class ArtTypesXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
     String sToSearch = "This is a test\nAnother test\n#art\n#paintings#collections";

     Matcher mHashThenWord = Pattern.compile("#(\\w+)").matcher(sToSearch);

     while(mHashThenWord.find())  {
        System.out.println(mHashThenWord.group(1));
     }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java ArtTypesXmpl
art
paintings
collections
```

JavaDoc on `Pattern` and `Matcher`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html

Comment: this is really cool. Never quite seen all this magnificence anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
String[] sp = str.split("\\s|\\n");
```

From [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

Twelve characters have special meanings in regular expressions: the backslash `\`, the caret `^`, the dollar sign `$`, the period or dot `.`, the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`, the question mark `?`, the asterisk or star `*`, the plus sign `+`, the opening parenthesis `(`, the closing parenthesis `)`, the opening square bracket `[`, and the opening curly brace `{`. These special characters are often called *metacharacters*.

Comment: Escaping those characters isn't necessary, but at least credit [the place](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) you're lifting that text from.